# xcode iOS has disappeared! Only Mac project templates available now

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk, corruption

My xcode base SDK has disappeared and I can't get it back. Even a New project offers me only MAC templates, not iOS templates.

Trying to fix it, I uninstalled and then installed 4.2. Everything looked fine (i.e. both iOS and MAC templates were available) I opened a project I have been working on and WHAP! No base SDK avaiable and many files showed in Navigator as missing, including Foundation and Core.

Two questions: what happened and how do I recover. I don't want to recreate my project if I can avoid that.

Comment: What if you browse the respective folder with a file manager?

Answer (score 0):

> I uninstalled and then installed 4.2

But the current version of Xcode is 4.6.2.

The underlying problem here is probably one of these:

- You need to downgrade your project's Deployment Target to match that of your version of Xcode. For example, with Xcode 4.2, you'd need to set this to iOS 5.
- You need to create a new Scheme. Sometimes the scheme gets corrupted or confused. I've seen this, for example, when renaming a project.

Oh, one more thing: be sure to get rid of the Derived Data, just in case there's been an indexing problem. https://stackoverflow.com/a/6247073/341994